# GitIgnore ! File in Subdirectories

Tags: git, ignore, subdirectory, inverse

I have the following files & directory structure in my git project.

> conf/.gitignore
>   conf/_conf.example
>   conf/conf.sh
>   conf/init/_init.example
>   conf/init/init.sh

The git ignore is written as:

```
# Ignore all files except the examples.

*
!.gitignore
!_conf.example
!init/_init.example
```

I've added the .gitignore to git.  All files are ignored except for conf.sh, which resides in the same directory as the .gitignore file.  My intent is not to ignore the _init.example file in the nested init directory, but my configuration is not doing this correctly.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can I ask what your `git status` says?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `*` excludes the *conf* subdirectory so no further rules will ever be evaluated with respect to it. Then the same argument applies to the subsequent *init* subdirectory, and so on.

Generally, you undo `*` by including back the directory to be examined, for example:

```
*
!conf
```

And depending on your version of git you may have to go on and add,

```
!conf/init
!conf/init/_init.example
```

**but from my experience it is best to avoid the asterisk entirely in non-leaf `.gitignore` files.** Simply be specific about the files you want to exclude, recreating the directory structure where necessary, as part of your `.gitignore` hierarchy.

The following is subjective: I always found it easier to have one top-level `.gitignore` file in the repository, where all ignores are spelled out explicitly, coupled with simple globbing for file extensions.

Further, the recent [`git check-ignore`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-check-ignore.html) addition to git is useful to debug the more complex ignore scenarios, but, subjectively again, I prefer not to get into them to begin with.

Comment: Thanks!  I followed your subjective advice and it resulted in a clear, working configuration.